# How to use gulp to combine coffee-script and js together in html

Tags: coffeescript, gulp

I would like to compile coffee to js and then combine the two js files to one js. How can I do that? I tried gulp-useref but seems it cannot achieve that.

Before:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="lib.js"></script>
    <script src="page.coffee" type="text/coffeescript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="mian.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Read and transpile your coffee [gulp-coffee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-coffee/)
2. Read your javascript
3. Merge them using [merge2](https://github.com/teambition/merge2) and [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat/)
4. ([uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify/) them) This is optional, but i'd recommend minified code for production
5. Write them to the filesystem

---

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpCoffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var gulpUglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');
var merge2 = require('merge2');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var coffee = gulp.src('file2.coffee') //1
        .pipe(gulpCoffee()); //1
    var js = gulp.src('file1.js'); //2

    merge2([coffee, js]) //3
        .pipe(gulpConcat('main.js')) //3
        .pipe(gulpUglify()) //4
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest')); //5
});
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this by merging two streams. But the source files (js & coffee) are listed in html files and I don't want to config them again in gulp tasks. That's why I tried gulp-useref, which will parse the html files.

Comment: The only idea I have now is to write a plugin similar with gulp-useref and it will compile coffee additionally.